# How to use ng2-bootstrap with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

How to use Bootstrap (or any other) component library?
Christopher · 6 minutes ago

Can anyone help with sample code on how to include bootstrap components

I am trying to use the bootstrap alert. I installed the npm package and added the package as :

**alert-component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import { AlertComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'alert-demo',
  template: `
    <alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
      {{ alert?.msg }}
    </alert>
    <alert dismissOnTimeout="3000">This alert will dismiss in 3s</alert>
    <button type="button" class='btn btn-primary' (click)="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
  `,
  directives: [AlertComponent, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AlertDemoComponent {
  public alerts:Array<Object> = [
    {
      type: 'danger',
      msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.'
    },
    {
      type: 'success',
      msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.',
      closable: true
    }
  ];
  public closeAlert(i:number):void {
    this.alerts.splice(i, 1);
  }
  public addAlert():void {
    this.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!', type: 'warning', closable: true});
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/router";
import { MessagesComponent } from "./messages/messages.component";
import { AuthenticationComponent } from "./auth/authentication.component";
import {NavBarComponent} from "./navbar.component"
import {AlertDemoComponent} from "./alert.component"
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <navbar></navbar>
            <alert-demo></alert-demo>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavBarComponent,AlertDemoComponent]
})
@Routes([
    {path: '/', component: MessagesComponent},
    {path: '/auth', component: AuthenticationComponent}
])
export class AppComponent {}
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
    (function(global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'js/app', // 'dist',
        'rxjs':                       'js/vendor/rxjs',
        '@angular':                   'js/vendor/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'boot.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap": {defaultExtension: 'js'}
    };

    var paths= {
    "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap":   "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap"
  }


    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
        'ng2-bootstrap'
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        paths: paths
    };

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

I am getting error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap"
ng2-bootstrap
Error: patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:27
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29
Error loading http://localhost:3000/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap as "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap" from http://localhost:3000/js/app/alert.component.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have *ng2-bootstrap* in your `package.json` dependencies:

```
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.16",
```

And that it is installed in your project's `node_modules`, you need to make sure to include ng2-bootstrap library in your index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Once you have this, you should remove it from your *packageNames* in `systemjs.config.js`:

```
var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade'
    ];
```

In addition, ng2-bootstrap has a dependency on *moment.js* which means you need to also include it in your dependencies:

```
"moment": "^2.13.0"
```

And you need to update your `systemjs.config.js` to contain mapping:

```
var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
    };
```

Once you have all of these in place, you should be able to use any of the ng2-bootstrap components with no issues.

Comment: if i have the bootstrap src in script, during the production code, how will the index.html reference the node_modules folder. my assumption was we do not include the node_modules in the final version deployment folder. please correct if wrong. Alternatively i came across to use gulp to actually take those node_modules REQUIRED files and put into a seperate folder that will be used in the live env.

Answer (score 0):

**systemjs.config**

```
    (function(global) {

        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        var map = {
            'app':                        'js/app', // 'dist',
            'rxjs':                       'js/vendor/rxjs',
            '@angular':                   'js/vendor/@angular',
            'moment':                     'js/vendor/moment/moment.js',
            'ng2-bootstrap':              'js/vendor/ng2-bootstrap'
        };

        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        var packages = {
            'app':                        { main: 'boot.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'ng2-bootstrap':              { defaultExtension: 'js' }
        };

        var packageNames = [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/testing',
            '@angular/upgrade'
        ];

        // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
            packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        });

        var config = {
            map: map,
            packages: packages
   };
// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
        if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

        System.config(config);

    })(this);
```

**gulpfile**

```
gulp.task('vendor', function() {

    // Angular 2 Framework
    gulp.src('node_modules/@angular/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/@angular'));

    //ES6 Shim
    gulp.src('node_modules/es6-shim/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/es6-shim/'));

    //reflect metadata
    gulp.src('node_modules/reflect-metadata/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/reflect-metadata/'));

    //rxjs
    gulp.src('node_modules/rxjs/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/rxjs/'));

    //systemjs
    gulp.src('node_modules/systemjs/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/systemjs/'));

    //bootstrap
    gulp.src('node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/ng2-bootstrap'));

   //moment.js for bootstrap datepicker
    gulp.src('node_modules/moment/**')
            .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/moment'));

    //zonejs
    return gulp.src('node_modules/zone.js/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(vendor + '/zone.js/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is experiencing additional problems and getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: System.registerDynamic is not a function.
```

**Solution:** Move your ng2-bootstrap script tag after your systemjs script tag in your index.html file. This shouldn't matter, but as of right now it does.

So if you're using Angular2-quickstart, your index.html should look like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>
</html>
```